# Google Apps & Salesforce - SAML SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

If I'm using Salesforce as the Identity Provider to log in to my Google Apps email, what happens when Salesforce wants to verify my identity by emailing a login verification code?

As I think about it:

- I can't log in to Salesforce b/c I don't have the verification code
- I can't get the verification code because I need to log in to Salesforce to access my email.

I'm sure there's a work-around for this, but don't see anything in the docs and would want to resolve this before considering an implementation.  Have you run into this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option, that doesn't involve opening IP ranges, is to enable [SMS Identity Confirmation](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Summer12/sms+identity+confirmation) by navigating to ***Your Name* | Setup | Security Controls | Session Settings** and checking **Enable SMS-based identity confirmation**.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an elegant solution, but I have a solution nonetheless. You can remove the requirement for verification codes by adding your known trusted network IP ranges (Setup > Security Controls > Network Access) or by contacting salesforce.com support and getting the verification process disabled.

You can only enter small IP-ranges manually so if your users are logging in from the public internet you'd need to add every range possible. This could be time consuming but there is [an app for that](https://na15.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tF0000000JHh6)!

Answer (score 2):

If you have Enterprise/Platform or Unlimited edition, you can enter a large trusted IP range (eg: 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255) in your Profile via:

Setup -> Manage Users -> Profile -> Click the profile you use -> in the related list at Login IP Ranges, click new, and enter the large IP range.